# Open new activity based on shared preferences value

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

What I'm trying to do is check if user is logged in to the android application and then deleted the application from history and reopend it to make him move to `User_Menu` activity, not to the `MainActivity`. I used shared preferences but it didn't work.

In `MainActivity` I put a function check to check if user is logged in:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button login;
    Button reg;
    Button guest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        check();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4")));

        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        reg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        guest=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    }

    public void check()
    {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = preferences.getString("Name", "");
        if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),User_Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent); /* Edit the value here*/
        }
    }
}
```

And on `User_Menu` activity where user go when he logs in, I put:

```
public class User_Menu extends ActionBarActivity {
    AskConnection db;

    Button lbsButton;
    Button guideButton;
    Button duaButton;
    Button mediaButton;
    Button askButton;
    Button azkarButton;
    Button logoutButton;
    static String nameU=null;
    private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        //nameU=new String();
        /*  setLanguage();
        showUserSettings();*/
        android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4")));
        try {
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<LoginConnection.jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = LoginConnection.jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                nameU=json_data.getString("name");

                //list.add(answer);
                //  print(nameU);
            }

            display();
        } catch(JSONException e1){
            print("No Data Found");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

when i tried this it first work correctly but after I login and reopen the application exceptions appear that till me unable to open `User_Menu` activity

Comment: So... what is your question? What is the problem? What happened? What did you try? Why didn't it work? And pleeeease, spend more than 4 seconds on formulating your question, fix your formatting issues, and, well, try some punctuation.

Comment: whay=t i want to do is i want to check if there is a name stored in the SharedPreferences to open the Menu_User Activity if not open the MainActivity so if name.equalsIgnoreCase("") is true it will open the MainActivity   and i added the result when i tried the code

Answer (score 0):

In the method to check if there is a name in the SharedPreferences you start the menu activity if there is no user in the preferences, but is that really what you want to do? I would expect, that if name.equalsIgnoreCase("") is true you would want to start the menu activity.

Furthermore you should think about adding

- FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

to the intent to clear all activities from the activity stack before you change to the menu activity.

Comment: yes i want to check if there is a name stored in the SharedPreferences  to open the Menu_User Activity if not open the MainActivity so if name.equalsIgnoreCase("")  is true it will open the MainActivity